# Got an exception of TypeError: window.parent.leftframe.document.viewForm is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, typeerror

This JS is working at IE, but when I use Chrome, always get this error:

exception
:
TypeError: window.parent.leftframe.document.viewForm is not a function at Checked

I use this code to check the form input and return true if user inputs command in that form)

Can you shed lights on this?

Thanks!
Vince

```
function Checked() 
    {
    if (window.parent.leftframe.document.viewForm.changed.value == "true") {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        for (k = 0; k < 30; k++) {
            memcom = "member[" + i + "].command";    
            if (window.parent.leftframe.document.viewForm(memcom) != null && window.parent.leftframe.document.viewForm(memcom).value != "") {
        return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
    }
}
```

viewFrom in this JSP:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>

<table class="Product" cellspacing="1">
    <html:form action="/viewSubmit" method="post" onsubmit="return onSubmitForm()">
        <input type="hidden" name="submited" value="false"> 
        <html:hidden property="action"></html:hidden>
        <html:hidden property="changed"></html:hidden>
......

                <logic:equal name="viewForm" property="opt.withMemberList" value="true">
.......

                        <td colspan="3" class="Product2">
                <a href="#" onclick="return <bean:write name="viewForm" property="listpURL" listp="false"/>"><IMG src="images/product_list_button.gif" border="0" /></a>                
            </td>
..........              <tr>
                        <logic:iterate id="member" name="viewForm" property="members" indexId="i">
                ....                
                <html:hidden indexed="true" name="member" property="remark"></html:hidden>                                  
                <td align="location" class="Product2">
                    <html:select name="member" indexed="true" property="command" disabled="false">
                    <html:options name="member"  property="commandSelection"/>                                              
                    </html:select>          
                </td>
                         </tr>
......
        </logic:equal>
    </html:form>
</table>        

</html>
```

Chrome Devtools output:

I can see this in the window.parent.leftframe.document.viewForm

```
name:"member[0].command"
nextElementSibling:null
nextSibling:text
nodeName:"SELECT"
nodeType:1
nodeValue:null
nonce:""
```

I see [31].name when mouse moves to the name, same as others.
How can I get the nodeValue from this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It may be more correct to say that IE is not giving you an error (that you *should* be getting).

In the first `if` statement, `window...viewForm...` is being treated as an object with a property called 'changed', which has a property called 'value'; however, later you reference the same thing as a function. Looking at the `document` property/object in Chrome, I do not see a `viewForm` property (thus, the error in Chrome).

Also, it would be very helpful, in the future, if you posted the HTML bit that is being used.

Comment: I added ViewForm code as well. This has been run on IE for a long time, but we counter this issue on Chrome, not sure if this is related to the AcionForm.

Comment: 1) It looks like the ViewForm code is java, not javascript. 2) What is `window.parent.leftframe.document.viewForm` defined to be?

Comment: After investigated this project which written by other people, I found that the viewForm is in that JSP using Strtuts 1.  I also updated the viewForm codes as well.

Comment: Instead of using `.name`, use `.value` (in javascript). I _think_ `.getParameter("command")` will work in JSP - but that starts getting outside of my domain.

Comment: Thank guys, .getParameter  doesn't work. I used .value and it worked.